# ios Swift3 Dynamically increasing Cell Row Height does not work for one to many relationship

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3, ios10

[image]
In Core Data I have a one-to-many relationship between contact and location entities. In my tableview I want to display the contact information as header in a Section and the associated locations for each contact inside the cell as multiple rows.

I am able to display the header (with contact information) and the cell ( with locations) dynamically. I set the cell as Custom with Row Height 200. I also set the rowHeight in my program as below:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
     //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     //return 200.0
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Here is my cellForRowAt function:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellView:UIView = UIView()
    let cell:EndPtTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "endPtCell", for: indexPath) as! EndPtTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let endpt:EndPtListTableViewController.EndPt = allEndpts[indexPath.row]

   var yVal:Double  = 10.0
    for locationDict in locationDictArray {
        let location:String = locationDict["locationName"]!
        let zip:String = locationDict["zip"]!
        let locationAndZipLabel = UILabel()
        locationAndZipLabel.text = location + ", " + zip
        locationAndZipLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:  UIFontTextStyle.body)
        locationAndZipLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 30.0, y:yVal, width: 350, height: 15)
        locationAndZipLabel.tag = 5
        yVal = yVal + 25.0
        cellView.addSubview(locationAndZipLabel)
    }
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellView)
    return cell
}
```

The cell displays the location and Zip values for each location in different rows, but does not expand the cell row height dynamically. As you can see the second row is partially displayed.

How can I dynamically expand the cell Row Height based on number of rows inserted?

Comment: You are adding 'cellView.addSubview(locationAndZipLabel) ' in cellForRowAt method which won't resize your cell. You need to add it to storyboard and have appropriate constraints for it.

Comment: I still need to add label in cellForRowAt method correct?, but in addition I have to make changes to storyboard. Can you show an example please?

Comment: Fixed:
I had it wrong. I was adding all the locations to the same cell. I just changed the logic by (1) saving the current section in titleForHeaderInSection (2) defining the location label in a cell (3) Accessing the location in CellForRowAt with currentSection as section and indexPath.row as location row